# How to display the final value of a counter at the beginning of a document?

Tags: counters

At the beginning of my document, I have created a counter using `\newcounter`. Over the course of the document, this counter is increases using `\stepcounter`. How can I display the final value of the counter in a place prior to the the final occurrence of `\stepcounter`, such as at the beginning of the document?

Comment: You need to write the value into the `.aux` file, then you can read it back at the beginning. I'm sure someone will post some code for that soon.

Comment: As it stands, the question doesn't even mention ConTeXt, and only shows LaTeX commands. I guess that having two answers with a total of 17 upvotes *is* receiving enough attention.

Comment: The question is many months old and already solved, but I found I have the same problem, but in ConTeXt, which does not have the `totcount` package. Would it have been better if I had started a new, identical question, but specific to ConTeXt, rather than add a bounty?

Comment: @Village: You could have asked a new ConTeXt specific question. A bounty is also ok, but I wouldn't have chosen the "This question has not received enough attention" reason.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`totcount`](https://ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package does just it:

```
\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{mycount}
```

With `\newtotcounter{mycount}` you define a new counter and also register it; if the counter is already defined (say `chapter`), then

```
\regtotcounter{chapter}
```

will simply register it to **totcount** system.

You can print the final value of the counter (as it was on the preceding LaTeX run) by `\total{mycount}`. There is also `\totvalue{mycount}` which is the analog of `\value{mycount}`. A couple of LaTeX runs are necessary to get synchronization.

Comment: Package `totcount` used `\AtEndDocument` while defining a new counter. Because of this, it may fail, e.g. try `\AtEndDocument{\blindtext[10]My counter is
  \stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.}` after `\newtotcounter{mycounter}`. It would be better, if the package would use something like `\AfterClosingMainAux` or `\AfterLastShipout` (package [atveryend](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend)). Nevertheless your answer is the better one.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I agree, although this is a bit contrived example. Maybe you can ask the author about this.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I ran into exactly the problem when I tried to define this in a preamble, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538566/how-to-set-a-counter-like-last-page-so-i-can-call-its-last-value . It's showing an error as ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \c@mycount@totc

Answer (score 17):

Here is some code for Martin's comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlfile}% KOMA-Script package with it's own documentation

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\demomycounter}{% This is only for demonstration and not part of the suggestion
  \@whilenum \value{page}<2\do {%
    Usage of mycounter with value \stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.\par
  }%
}
\newcommand*\storecounteratend[1]{% command to tell LaTeX to save the last value for the next run
  \BeforeClosingMainAux{%
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\restorecounteratbegin{#1}{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\restorecounteratbegin}[2]{% used at the aux file
  \expandafter\gdef\csname stored@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\storedcounter}[1]{% user command to ask for the value
  \@ifundefined{stored@#1}{???}{\csname stored@#1\endcsname}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mycounter}
\storecounteratend{mycounter}

\begin{document}
Last value of mycounter was \storedcounter{mycounter}.
\demomycounter
\end{document}
```

Instead of using `\BeforeClosingMainAux` from package [scrlfile](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script), you may use `\AfterLastShipout` with package [atveryend](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/atveryend).

Another solution would be to use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. In this case, you simply have to write a label at the end of the document and may use `\ref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrlfile}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\BeforeClosingMainAux{\label{mycounter}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\demomycounter}{% This is only for demonstration and not part of the suggestion
  \@whilenum \value{page}<2\do {%
    Usage of mycounter with value \refstepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.\par
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Last value of mycounter was \ref{mycounter}.
\demomycounter
\end{document}
```

If you need not a reference to the counter but the value, you may combine the second suggestion with package [refcount](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount).

Comment: `scrlfile` no longer exisits ????

Comment: @CasperYC Why do you think so? `scrlfile` is still part of KOMA-Script (see the link in my answer).

Comment: Not sure why I posted that...maybe at that time 3 years ago, MikTeX just wouldn't find it...

Comment: @CasperYC So maybe you should delete this comment, because the reply is surely: It still exists.

Answer (score 14):

In ConTeXt, you don't need any external package to display the final value of a counter: it is available by using the macro `\lastcounter[...]`. For example:

```
\definecounter[countername][numberconversion=Characters]

\starttext

There are \lastcounter[countername] counters.

\dorecurse{5}
  {\convertedcounter[countername] randomtext \incrementcounter[countername] \crlf }

\stoptext
```

To access the last value of the counter at the Lua end, use

```
structures.counters.last("countername", 1)
```

Comment: In Lua, I have tried many combinations, `tex.count.lastcounter[countername]`, `tex.lastcounter.countername`, `tex.count["lastcounter[countername]"]`, etc., but cannot find a syntax which is correct.

Comment: `tex.count` table is only for counters defined using `\newcount`. I edited the answer to show how to access the counters defined in ConTeXt using Lua.

Answer (score 2):

The `xassoccnt` package defines similar strategies (although not yet in its full functionality like `totcount` package) with `\NewTotalDocumentCounter` for new counters or `\RegisterTotalDocumentCounter` for already existing counters.

The macro `\TotalValue` is expandable (see the example) and can be used to retrieve the value of a counter at any position within the document body after the 2nd compilation run.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nonumberofruns]{xassoccnt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\NewTotalDocumentCounter{foocntr}

\RegisterTotalDocumentCounter{section}

\begin{document}

The total value of section is \TotalValue{section}, whereas there are \TotalValue{foocntr} foos. 

The real name is \TotalCounterInternalNameExp{section}%


\ifnum\TotalValue{section} > 1\relax Hooray \else only one section found\fi
\blinddocument

\setcounter{foocntr}{100}

\blinddocument


\setcounter{foocntr}{8472}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my life !!!!!