# Sum of counters at the beginning of file

Tags: counters

New to this forum, but long time TeX and LaTeX user. I've had this problem recently, for which I couldn't find a solution:

I'd like to print out the total possible score at a test at the top of the test. This is of course the total sum of scores of the different questions. I've thus thought of creating a counter

```
\newcounter{total}
\setcounter{total}{0}
```

at the beginning of the file, and at each question, I've used the command

```
\addtocounter{total}{ <the score at this question> }
```

But then, of course, the total score is effectively computed at the end of the document. How can I manage to print this score at the top of the document? Perhaps with a temporary external file, but I haven't looked into this...

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sounds like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/how-to-display-the-final-value-of-a-counter-at-the-beginning-of-a-document?rq=1 to me

Comment: Are you preparing some kind of exam sheet?

Comment: @JosephWright: thank you for the link, I'm going to look into it.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig: yes, I am. Is there any "automated" package for this that you know of?

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I suggest to take a look either at the »[exam](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam)« class or at packages like »[exsheets](http://ctan.org/pkg/exsheets)« or »[probsoln](http://ctan.org/pkg/probsoln)«.

Comment: @karlkoeller: thank you for the welcoming words! I'll take a look at the starter guide!