# How to get the amount of theorems in a section

Tags: counters

How can I get the number (i.e. amount) of theorems that appear in a particular section (or between any user determined beginning and end point) and display it in the document?

Comment: Perhaps some ideas can be extracted from [How to display the final value of a counter at the beginning of a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/5764) The suggestion is to use the [`totcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/totcount). Delimiting it to certain section might require special handling.

Comment: Are your theorem counters reset with every section?

Comment: @Werner No... they're not reset. Thank you for the reference to the other question, that seems relevant. It didn't come up when I searched/wrote my question.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that defines a few commands:

```
\newcounter{egbertmarker}
\newcommand{\theoremmarker}{%
    \stepcounter{egbertmarker}
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\definetotaltheoremcount\string{\theegbertmarker\string}\string{\the\value{dummytheorem}\string}
    }%
}
```

This does the following:

- defines a new counter which will increment each time you call `\theoremmarker`
- every time you call `\theoremmarker` a command will be written to the `\jobname.aux` file that defines how many `theorem` environments have been used since the last use `\theoremmarker`

The command `\theoremcount` gives you the value of the number of theorems in use at the current marker.

The code below writes and reads to `jobname.aux` so you'll need two compilations to stabilize.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetotaltheoremcount}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{c@totaltheorems\@roman{#1}}%
    {%
        \newcounter{totaltheorems\@roman{#1}}
        \setcounter{totaltheorems\@roman{#1}}{#2}
        \typeout{Defining a new counter: totaltheorems\@roman{#1}}
    }%
    {%
        \ifnum\value{totaltheorems\@roman{#1}}=#2
            \typeout{Total theorems for marker #1 match auxilary file (#2)}
        \else
            \typeout{Warning: total theorems for marker #1 updated from \the\value{totaltheorems\@roman{#1}} to #2-- recompile to fix}
        \fi
        \setcounter{totaltheorems\@roman{#1}}{#2}
    }%
}

% make the theorem environment increment 
% counter since last theorem
\newcounter{dummytheorem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\stepcounter{dummytheorem}}

% write the current number of theorems to a counter
\newcounter{egbertmarker}
\newcommand{\theoremmarker}{%
    \stepcounter{egbertmarker}
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \string\definetotaltheoremcount\string{\theegbertmarker\string}\string{\the\value{dummytheorem}\string}
    }%
}

% command to count the theorems 
\newcommand{\theoremcount}{%
    \@ifundefined{c@totaltheorems\roman{egbertmarker}}%
    {%
        ??%
    }%
    {%
        \the\value{totaltheorems\roman{egbertmarker}}
    }%
    \setcounter{dummytheorem}{0}
}
\begin{document}

\newcount\tmp
\tmp=0
\loop
\begin{theorem}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\advance\tmp by 1
\ifnum\tmp<2
    \repeat

    \theoremmarker

    number of theorems since last marker:\theoremcount

    \tmp=0
    \loop
    \begin{theorem}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{theorem}
    \advance\tmp by 1
    \ifnum\tmp<3
        \repeat

        \theoremmarker
        number of theorems since last marker:\theoremcount

    \tmp=0
    \loop
    \begin{theorem}
        \lipsum[1]
    \end{theorem}
    \advance\tmp by 1
    \ifnum\tmp<4
        \repeat

        \theoremmarker
        number of theorems since last marker:\theoremcount
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to manage counting the number of theorems is to use a counter:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\createtheorems}[1]{\multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{\begin{theorem}A theorem\end{theorem}}}

\newcounter{theoremcount}
\newcommand{\startcountingtheorems}{\setcounter{theoremcount}{\value{theorem}}}
\newcommand{\stopcountingtheorems}{\setcounter{theoremcount}{\numexpr\value{theorem}-\value{theoremcount}\relax}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\startcountingtheorems% ================= START THEOREM COUNT
\createtheorems{7}
\stopcountingtheorems%  ================= STOP THEOREM COUNT
I counted~\thetheoremcount{} theorems.% 7 theorems

\section{Another section}
\createtheorems{2}
\startcountingtheorems% ================= START THEOREM COUNT
\createtheorems{4}

\section{Final section}
\createtheorems{5}
\stopcountingtheorems%  ================= STOP THEOREM COUNT
I counted~\thetheoremcount{} theorems.% 9 theorems
\end{document}
```

Counting "zones" are designated using `\startcountingtheorems` and `\stopcountingtheorems`, while the counter `theoremcount` contains the last counted theorem quantity.

It would be possible to extend this to be used as a `\label`-`\ref`-like quantity as well. In that way you could recall the number of theorems within a certain scope (could be the entire document) *anywhere* in the document. At the moment, you would only obtain the correct count *after* `\stopcountingtheorems`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, using standard LaTeX commands and counters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcounter{numthrms}
\newenvironment{Theorem}{\begin{theorem}
                     \stepcounter{numthrms}}{%
                     \end{theorem}}
\newcommand{\numtheorems}{\thenumthrms}
\newcommand{\resetnumthrms{\setcounter{numthrms}{0}}                         
\begin{document} 
\begin{Theorem}
  My first theorem
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
  My second theorem
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Theorem}
  My 3th theorem
\end{Theorem}
I have \numtheorems{} theorems.\resetnumthrms
\begin{Theorem}
  Another theorem
\end{Theorem}
Theorems added: \numtheorems.
\end{document}
```

[image: Num theorems counter]