# How to get the number of chapters in a document

Tags: chapters

`TeX` specialists!

I write a document in `LaTeX` using the `book` document class.

In a section at the beginning of my document I describe the structure of the document, listing all the chapters and short description of their content. I would like to start that section with the information how many chapters I have in the document in total.

So, is there a way I can get the total number of chapters in the document to print it in the text?

```
\section{Structure of the document}
The document is organized into ?? chapters as follows:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Chapter \ref{chap:intro} brings the introduction.
\item Chapter \ref{chap:problem} describes the problem we try to solve.
...
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: you can use like `The document is organized into \ref{chap:last} chapters as follows:`

Comment: Good point. It means I need to update it if I add another chapter to the end but it should work well enough. Thanks.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to display the final value of a counter at the beginning of a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/5764)

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: None of the suggested solutions worked for me, so I stayed with using the label of the last chapter for the count.

Answer (score 10):

This is possible with `totcount` package, for example!

`\regtotcounter{chapter}` registers an existing counter name and stores the value at the end of the compilation to the `.aux` file, during the  second compilation the total value can be obtained with `\total{chapter}`.

There's no need to adjust a label to the last chapter then manually.

My own package `xassoccnt` allows for total counters as well.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{chapter}

\begin{document}


\section{Structure of the document}
The document is organized into \total{chapter} chapters as follows:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Chapter \ref{chap:intro} brings the introduction.
\item Chapter \ref{chap:problem} describes the problem we try to solve.
\end{enumerate}


\chapter{First}  \label{chap:intro}


\chapter{Second} \label{chap:problem}


\chapter{Third} 

\chapter{Four}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: Here's a 'proof' that splitting a document into `myintro.tex` etc. still leads to a working document!

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{filecontents}{myintro.tex}
\section{Structure of the document}
The document is organized into \total{chapter} chapters as follows:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Chapter \ref{chap:intro} brings the introduction.
\item Chapter \ref{chap:problem} describes the problem we try to solve.
\end{enumerate}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{chapter}



\begin{document}
\InputIfFileExists{myintro}{}{}
\chapter{First}  \label{chap:intro}


\chapter{Second} \label{chap:problem}


\chapter{Third} 

\chapter{Four}

\end{document}
```

**Update No 2**

In case `\appendix` is used, the `chapter` counter is reset. in this case use `\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{chapter}{allchapters}`, where `allchapters` ignores the reseting of `chapter`.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\DeclareTotalAssociatedCounters{chapter}{allchapters}

\begin{document}
\section{Structure of the document}
The document is organized into \TotalValue{allchapters} chapters as follows:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Chapter \ref{chap:intro} brings the introduction.
\item Chapter \ref{chap:problem} describes the problem we try to solve.
\end{enumerate}


\chapter{First}  \label{chap:intro}


\chapter{Second} \label{chap:problem}


\chapter{Third} 

\chapter{Four}

\appendix

\chapter{One of Appendix}
\chapter{Two of Appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this approach. But it always prints value 1. I assume the problem is I need to use the \total{chapter} reference inside of the first chapter, thus having the variable initialized again and so far counted only one chapter...

Comment: @Sharg: No, the position of `\total{chapter}` doesn't matter unless you would use it in the preamble. The total chapter counter has a different name as `chapter` and does not interfere. Apparently you're doing something wrong

Comment: I do not want to post the whole document. Is it possible that the separation into multiple tex files and using `\input{intro.tex}` might be the problem?

Comment: @Sharg: Splitting the document causes more bad things than good ones, but in this case, I am not sure this is the issue. `totcount` normaly writes to the `\jobname.aux` file, not to something different.

Comment: @Sharg: I just tested with a splitted document -- it still works!

Comment: @Sharg I'm having the same issue as you had. It always prints value 1. Did you solve this problem? If yes, how?

Comment: Sent u a mail :) But don't waste to much time to dig into it. It's just a convenience feature and if it doesn't work its not a big deal. Just wanted to ask if Sharg maybe found an easy solution.

Comment: @YannicKlem: I'll try later on, I've seen the mail already, however.

Comment: @YannicKlem: I've answered your mail with a working solution, but I got no feedback.

Comment: Oh sorry I postboned to try your suggested package but somehow forgot it. Will try today

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I missed the e-mail.
I have not found the working solution. I just resigned and used the id of the last chapter to print the number representing the number of chapters.

Comment: @Sharg: I did not send an email to you ;-)

Comment: @Sharg: I've added another solution, perhaps this works for you

Answer (score 2):

If you're only counting chapters and don't have a counter-resetting Appendix in there somewhere, you can set a `\label` at the end of the document that specifically captures the current value of `\arabic{chapter}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{chapter}}%
  \label{chap:last}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Structure of the document}
The document has \ref{chap:last} chapters.

\multido{\i=1+1}{57}{\chapter{A chapter}}

\end{document}
```