# Show chapter number along with Total Chapter Count in Chapter title - Memoir document class

Tags: memoir, counters, totalcount

How to show chapterNo/TotalChapterCount in the Chapter title of memoir document.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First}

    \lipsum

    \chapter{Second}

    \lipsum     


\end{document}
```

I want the chapter title as

Chapter 1/2
First

I dont need any changes in tableofcontents.

[image: ChapterTitle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This isn't a pure memoir solution as it uses the `titlesec` package to customise the appearance of the titles. Also, thanks to @egreg for pointing out that `titlesec` and `memoir` don't always play well together. See [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012/about-memoir-and-titlesec-incompatibility). For a `memoir` solution see [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448335/128068) of @daleif.

Using the `totcount` package (as described in [How to get the number of chapters in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290374/how-to-get-the-number-of-chapters-in-a-document)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter/\total{chapter}}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\lipsum
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of totcount package, but how to add that to \chaptertitlename was my problem.

Comment: You should be aware that titlesec and memoir don’t go along well

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I wasn't fully aware of the potential incompatibility issues. Have updated my disclaimer to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to Milos answer, the same in just `memoir`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{chapter}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\chapnumfont \thechapter/\total{chapter}}


\begin{document}


    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First}

    \lipsum

    \chapter{Second}

    \lipsum     


\end{document}
```

You'll need to adapt it to what ever chapter style you are using.

Comment: Thanks I was really stuck up at this, how to adapt it to ell chapterstyle.  Great help.