# Displaying a counter that is computed later

Tags: counters, auxiliary-files

Most probably a trivial question for you: I have a counter `\thetotalnoexercices` that I compute while compiling my book, but I want to refer to it in the introduction ("This book contains ... exercises").
I should write it to the `.aux` file but the mechanism seems unclear to me (according to my trials!).
Many thanks in advance! Best, O.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/35864 can help you.

Comment: You can simply set a \label at the last exercise and then use \ref.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you! I settled for simplicity and used the totcount packages. Ulrike's solution is perfect for simple files, it took me a while to understand it, but my exercises are numbered according to chapter-exerciseno-questionno. And the label mechanism takes care only of one counter (the last one that goes through refstepsounter I think). Thanks!