# Read variable before assigned

Tags: variable

I have a tabularx environment, with the first column containing each line   number. This number is incremented automatically thanks to a variable:

```
\newcounter{versionscnt}
```

and then for each line:

```
\addtocounter{versionscnt}{1} \theversionscnt
```

This works perfectly fine.

But now I would need to print the total number of lines (ie the last value of my counter) BEFORE the tabularx. Is there a way for me to do that?

Thanks a lot for your time.

PS: I found some really long solutions on this forum, for related issues, but 1) I did not understand them and 2) I don't think that this requires 50 lines of code (but I might be wrong, I don't know)...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how you currently use your counter in the tabularx environment. Testing ideas is a lot easier then.

Comment: [How to display the final value of a counter at the beginning of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34789/134144) could be related.

Comment: Thank you leandriis and Alan Munn, exactly what I needed!